# In Numbers 22:41, how should בָּמוֹת בָּעַל (Bamoth-baal, Strong's h1120 h1120) be understood?

Tags: hebrew, numbers

In the NLT, the two forms of the same word are translated as "Bamoth-baal":

> [Num 22:41 NLT] (41) The next morning Balak took Balaam up to **Bamoth-baal**. From there he could see some of the people of Israel spread out below him.

[image: Partial entry in interlinear]

The Greek has:

> Brenton(i) 41 And it was morning; and Balac took Balaam, and brought him up to **the pillar of Baal**, [τὴν [στήλην](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AE%CE%BB%CE%B7) τοῦ Βααλ]), and shewed him thence a part of the people.

It seems to be [mostly translated as "the high places of Baal"](https://biblehub.com/numbers/22-41.htm) but it seems to me that it refers to a [stepped temple/ziggurat.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat)

Please see [this related article in the Jewish Encyclopedia](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/7688-high-place).

And I'm curious how the etymology leads to the different readings as "high places" and "bamoth" and "Ba'al".

Comment: In Numbers 22:41 : "Bamot" (בָּמ֣וֹת) = "[the] heights" ; this term is also found in Numbers 21:20 "And-from-[the] heights" (Vu-Mi-Bamot, וּמִבָּמ֗וֹת)

Comment: Thanks. How might it be etymologically related to "Ba'al"?

Comment: "Bamot" (בָּמ֣וֹת) is the plural form of "Bamah" (בָּמָֽה) = "[the] High place" on which burnt offerings were sacrificed. - referenced in [1 Samuel 9:12] - "Bamot" does not always reference the Ba'al worship. * Yisraelites also used locations called "Ha-Bamah" ( הַבָּמָ֖ה ) = "The-High place" for their own burnt offerings (without the presence of idols) - referenced in [1 Samuel 9:25].

Comment: While the etymology is interesting, wouldn't it, in the context of the ancient world, refer to a ziggurat?

Answer (score 3):

In Numbers 22:41 : "Bamot" (בָּמ֣וֹת) = "[the] heights" is a term also found in Numbers 21:20 "And-from-[the] heights" (Umi-Bamot, וּמִבָּמ֗וֹת). **"Bamot" (בָּמ֣וֹת) is the plural form of "Bamah" (בָּמָֽה) = "[the] High place" on which burnt offerings were sacrificed. - referenced in [1 Samuel 9:12]**

- "Bamot" (בָּמ֣וֹת) does not always reference the Ba'al worship. * Yisraelites also used locations called "Ha-Bamah" ( הַבָּמָ֖ה ) = "The-High place" for their own burnt offerings (without the presence of idols) - referenced in [1 Samuel 9:25].

**Ha-Bamah (הַבָּמָ֖ה) for Yisraelites would not have been a Ziggurat - since Ziggurat requires cut stones for its altar, which are banned for burnt offerings (on a singular high place) in [Deuteronomy 27:5-6]:** [5] "And there, you shall build an altar to YHVH, your God, an altar of stones. **You shall not wield any iron upon them**." ( וּבָנִ֤יתָ שָּׁם֙ מִזְבֵּ֔חַ לַֽיהֹוָ֖ה אֱלֹהֶ֑יךָ מִזְבַּ֣ח אֲבָנִ֔ים לֹֽא־תָנִ֥יף עֲלֵיהֶ֖ם בַּרְזֶֽל )

[6] "**You shall build the altar of YHVH, your God, out of whole stones.** And on it, you shall offer up burnt offerings to YHVH, your God." ( אֲבָנִ֤ים שְׁלֵמוֹת֙ תִּבְנֶ֔ה אֶת־מִזְבַּ֖ח יְהֹוָ֣ה אֱלֹהֶ֑יךָ וְהַֽעֲלִ֤יתָ עָלָיו֙ עוֹלֹ֔ת לַֽיהֹוָ֖ה אֱלֹהֶֽיךָ )

However - **"Bamot Ba'al" ( בָּמ֣וֹת בָּ֑עַל )** alludes to plural platforms / "heights" (בָּמ֣וֹת) not just a single platform / "height"(בָּמָֽה) referenced **in Numbers 22:41. Ziggurat structures were constructed of 7 stages "high places" (for multiple altars made with cut stones) like the 7 altars made by Balaq (בָּלָ֔ק)** in Numbers 23:1-2.

**Numbers / Bamidbar 23:1** : Seven Altars for Seven Stages of a Ziggurat.

> Balaam said to Balaq, "Build me [seven altars] here, and prepare for me seven bulls and seven rams." (וַיֹּ֤אמֶר בִּלְעָם֙ אֶל־בָּלָ֔ק בְּנֵה־לִ֥י בָזֶ֖ה שִׁבְעָ֣ה מִזְבְּחֹ֑ת וְהָכֵ֥ן לִי֙ בָּזֶ֔ה שִׁבְעָ֥ה פָרִ֖ים וְשִׁבְעָ֥ה אֵילִֽים)

- It is possible the first set of **Seven Altars (Shib'ah Mizbechot, שִׁבְעָ֣ה מִזְבְּחֹ֑ת)** at "Bamot Ba'al" ( בָּמ֣וֹת בָּ֑עַל ) reference 7-Stages of a Ziggurat located in/near Qiryat Chuzot (קִרְיַ֥ת חֻצֽוֹת) "[the] city of streets".

Comment: Can you please explain why two versions of the word appear consecutively, or what the interlinear got wrong? Also, why the plural, "heights"? Thanks.

Comment: Baal was the primary god of the Phoenicians.  The high places were also used by other nations to worship their god.  The Law of Moses forbid worship/sacrifices at the high places.